# Weird symbols from fread (.txt)

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

Good evening!
I'm working on a task for my programming class where I must write a program (using Dev-c++) that reads and displays information about items from a .txt file and then gives an option to search and get information about a specific file (searching by name). Yet whenever I compile the code It doesn't show the written items only alot of gibberish symbols that don't make sense. I did some research and found out that the problem could maybe be related to not adding a binary 0 after the data read in. Is this the case? I'm sorry if this is a really simple problem, but I'm really new to programming and I could really use some help in understanding what's the problem:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define N 3

int info()
{
    printf ("Edgars Feldmanis \n");
    printf ("Apl.nr. 131RMC074 \n");
    printf ("8.var. punkts b \n");
    printf ("Blokveida ievade \n \n");
  }
    int main()
    {
        struct preces
    {
       char Nosaukums[15],Cena[10],Razotajs[15],Daudzums[10],Deriguma_termins[15];
     };


 struct preces prece[N];
 FILE *saraksts_st;
 int i,n;
 char x;
 unsigned int garums;

do
{
  printf("Izvelieties darbibu:\n");
  printf("1.Informacija par autoru un variantu\n");
  printf("2.Datu izvade un preces meklesana\n");
  printf("3.Pabeigt darbu\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  system("cls");
  if(n==1)info();
  else if(n==2)
  {
    if((saraksts_st=fopen("preces.txt","r"))==NULL) 
  {
    printf("Nevar atvert failu! \n");
    exit(1);
  }

   garums=sizeof(prece[0]);
   for(i=0; i<N && !feof(saraksts_st);i++)
   fclose(saraksts_st);
   printf("\nProduktu saraksts:\n");
   saraksts_st=fopen("preces.txt","r");
   printf("|   Nosaukums    |    Cena    |     Razotajs    |  Daudzums  |     Termins     | \n");


   for(i=0;i<N;i++)
   {printf("%|%15s | %10s | %15s | %10s | %15s |\n",prece[i].Nosaukums,prece[i].Cena,prece[i].Razotajs,prece[i].Daudzums,prece[i].Deriguma_termins);
    };

    printf("\nIevadiet meklejamas preces nosaukumu:\n");
    scanf("%s",&x);
    printf("|   Nosaukums    |    Cena    |     Razotajs    |  Daudzums  |     Termins     | \n");

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
        if(prece[i].Nosaukums=="x")
       {printf("|%15s | %10s | %15s | %10s | %15s |\n",prece[i].Nosaukums,prece[i].Cena,prece[i].Razotajs,prece[i].Daudzums,prece[i].Deriguma_termins);
        };  
      }
   getch();
   return 0;
   } 

   }
while(n!=3);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read documentation of every used function, e.g. [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Test them against runtime errors (probably using `perror` to handle errors), e.g. use item count returned by `scanf`. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). **Use the debugger** (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). BTW `<conio.h>` & `<windows.h>` are non-standard.

Comment: BTW, this is an English speaking site. So ask in English, and use English-looking messages and identifiers.

Comment: There's a loop printing all the values of the `prece` array yet that array is never initialized. It's no wonder it will dump all sorts of gibberish unto you. Later there is `if(prece[i].Nosaukums=="x")` which will be always false.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the answer. I'm a little confused though on how to perform the debugging - could you please perhaps explain it to me a little more?

Comment: Why `fclose` in a loop - of a file that is just opened? I also cannot find not a single file *reading* operation. Are you sure it's not necessary for what you are trying?

Comment: There is no (sound, complete) automatic debugging: [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). You need to *think*. The debugger is just a *tool* to understand the state of the [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running your program. You should read more about how to use your debugger.

Comment: @AndreasBombe Deepest apologies, but I'm not sure what you mean, sir.

Comment: BTW, Linux is probably a better developing environment than Windows. Consider installing Linux on your laptop

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can specify the numer of characters to be displayed in printf with %s. The routine just prints out data until it finds a zero character. Just set the last character of the string to '\0' and see if it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You really should read much more (in particular, read the documentation of every function you are using, like [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf); I'm guessing that your usage of [fread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) is completely wrong - it is meant for [binary files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file), not textual ones). As I commented,  There is no (sound, complete) automatic debugging: Read about the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). You need to think. The debugger is just a tool to understand the state of the [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) running your program. You should read more about how to use your debugger.

You have many bugs. Notice that `prece[i].Nosaukums=="x"` is always false (technically read about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). You need to use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to compare a string against a literal.

And your code is missing braces (for nested blocks). For instance, calling `fclose` inside a `for` loop is wrong:

```
 /* bad code */
 for(i=0; i<N && !feof(saraksts_st);i++)
   fclose(saraksts_st);
```

Take several hours or days to read more about C programming. Then, write your program again from scratch. Perhaps read several [tutorials](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) on C programming. If you persist on coding in C, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) - and also [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available -, notably to run your program step by step. Don't forget to code your program in parts: code a dozen lines at most, compile and test them (with the debugger), and once you are satisfied, repeat by growing your code.

BTW, my *opinion* is that learning programming with C is wrong (a [pedagogical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedagogy) mistake). You might try with [Scheme](http://schemers.org/) and read [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp).

Comment: Yeah.. we weren't taught the basics too well. Thanks for the effort guys, I'll do my best.